# On the relation between the closure of the range of $A$ and the closure of the range of $\overline A$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, functions, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $A:D(A)\subseteq H\to H$ be a densely defined, closable linear operator on the Hilbert space, $H$. We denote it's closure by $\overline A$. Suppose that $D(A)$ is also a core for $\overline A$.

Let $B:D(B)\subseteq H\to H$, a closed, potentially unbounded linear operator

We denote by $R(\cdot)$ and $N(\cdot)$ the range and kernel, respectively. Suppose that $R(A)\subseteq N(B)$. Then, $\overline{R(A)}\subseteq N(B)$, since the kernel of a closed linear operator is closed.

**My problem**: How exactly is it that one deduces
$$\overline{R(A)}\subseteq N(B)\implies\overline{R(\color{red}{\overline A})}\subseteq N(B)$$
from the fact that $D(A)$ is a core for $\overline A$? In addition, it seems me that we actually have the equality $\overline{R(A)}=\overline{R(\overline A)}$. I know that I should use that $D(A)$ is a core for $\overline A$ in order to pass from the range of $A$ to the range of $\overline A$, but I'm not sure on *how* it actually works.

Comment: $D$ being a core of an operator $C$ means that $\overline{C\lvert_D} = C$?

Comment: But as you remark $\overline{R(A))}= \overline{R(\overline{A})}$ already holds, which in turn follows from $\overline{R(A)}\supseteq R(\overline{A})$ which you get directly from the definition of the closure.

Comment: "$D$ being a core of an operator $C$ means that $\overline{C\lvert_D} = C$?", if $C$ is closed, yes, otherwise it means $\overline{C\lvert_D} = \overline{C}$

Comment: I think that I've maybe been reading too much into it on reflection ... by definition of the closure, it follows that $R(A)\subseteq R\left(\overline A\right)$. Then it follows that $\overline{R(A)}\subseteq \overline{R\left(\overline A\right)}$. This is only one direction of the proposed equality, but it's enough to draw the desired conclusion, right?

Comment: You actually want the _other_ inclusion. The one you have follows only from the fact that the closure is an extension, and thus holds for $\overline A$ being replaced by any extension of $A$. The conclusions are however clearly false in that setting. The other inclusion makes use of the concrete definition of the closure, you will only add things to the range that you can already approximate, hence the range of $\overline A$ is contained in the closure of $R(A)$.

Comment: These insights are very useful - my thanks. Can you give more detail as to why, despite having the inclusion I noted (from being an extension), "the conclusions are however clearly false"? As to the other part "The other inclusion ... in the closure of $R(A)$", would you be able to add more details/demonstrate this in an answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is a close-able operator, then
$$\overline{R(A)}\supseteq R\left(\overline A\right).$$
This follows directly from the definition of the closure, if $x\in D(\overline A)$ then $\overline A x$ is defined to be $\lim_n A x_n$ for any sequence $x_n\in D(A)$ converging to $x$ for which $Ax_n$ converges. Thus it is clear than any point in the range of $\overline A$ can be approximated by points $A x_n$ in $R(A)$, giving the above inclusion.

The other inclusion, namely
$$R(A)\subseteq R\left(\overline A\right),$$
follows automatically from $\overline A$ being an extension of $A$. This means $D(\overline A)\supseteq D(A)$ and $\overline A\lvert_{D(A)} = A$, hence
$$R\left(\overline A\right) = \overline A(D\left(\overline A\right)) \supseteq \overline A(D(A)) = A(D(A)) = R(A).$$

---

The first inclusion is the one that is relevant to your question. For if $R(A)\subseteq \ker(B)$ and $\ker(B)$ is closed, then
$$\ker(B) \supseteq \overline{R(A)}\supseteq R\left(\overline A\right)$$
which is what you want.

The second inclusion is not relevant to your question, if $A'$ is some arbitrary extension of $A$ the very same argument will give you $R(A)\subseteq R(A')$. However $\ker(B)\supseteq R(A)$ does not need to imply $\ker(B)\supseteq R(A')$ if $A'$ is an arbitrary extension of $A$ (if $x\notin D(A)$ and $v\notin \ker(B)$ then define $D(A') = \mathrm{span}\{ x, D(A)\}$ and $A'(\lambda x+ \xi) = \lambda v+A(\xi)$ for $\xi\in D(A)$).